# CakePHP model JOINS, missing fields

Tags: php, cakephp

Hey guys I am new to CakePHP and I am having a problem while joining two tables.

```
$options['joins'] = array(
          array('table' => 'options',
         'alias' => 'Options',
         'type' => 'LEFT',
         'fields' => array('Question.question', 'Options.option'),
         'conditions' => array(
         'Options.question_id = Question.id'))
         );

        $this->set('qq',$this->Question->find('all',$options));
```

I am getting only the fields of question table and not the fields of options table. How do I get the fields of options table also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to bind table.

```
$this->ModelName->bindModel(array
(
    'belongsTo' => array
    (
        'ModelToJoin' => array
        (
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array
            (
                'ModelToJoin.model_name_id = ModelName.id'
            )
        )
    )
));
```

According to your situation.

```
<?php

$this->Question->bindModel(array
(
    'hasMany' => array
    (
        'Options' => array
        (
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'type'       => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array
            (
                'Options.question_id = Question.id'
            )
        )
    )
));

$this->Question->find('all',array
(
    'fields' => array('Question.question', 'Options.option')
));
```

[**Read More On**](http://ask.amoeba.co.in/joining-multiple-tables-in-cakephp-using-bindmodel-method/)

Comment: i added this line after type=left...
'fields'=>array('Question.question,Options.option'),
its showing me all the fields of Question table. i want only the question column from Question table..