# Ticket System with cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.2

I'm attempting to create an ticket type of system for our companies IT related issues.

This ticket system should work as follows:

- User logs on and submits and 'IT Query'
- The query is saved with a unique ID, which is mailed to the user.
- The query is mailed to the IT Department.
- Responses to the queries are logged and when a user views the query, all these responses can be seen.

I'm having some issues with the last bullet.

Since I'm using two databases (it_queries with unique id ticket_id and it_responses with foreign id ticket_id), I'll have to have 3 views in each other in order for this to work.

I have the following in mind:
[image: What I have in mind]

How will I be able to achieve this or is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dipesh said, you should relate the tables correctly in order to make things easier and much more faster. Also, I would recommend you using the [CakePHP naming conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html), not only for Controllers, models and views, but also for the DataBase design. 
It will save you a lot of work and headaches. 
You can make use of the [cake bake functionality](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html) for it.

Apart from that, I don't see the point on using different views. You could use elements instead (view/eElements/), but i would do it much more simple.

You should take into account that one controller can (and probably will) make use of more than one model. Said this, your `view` action in your `ticketController` could call also to the `it_responses` table and retrieve the data in another array.

For example:

```
class TicketsController extends AppController {
    //using the It_response model
    var $uses = array('Ticket' , 'It_response');


    public function view($id){
        $ticketData = $this->Ticket->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Ticket.id' => $id));

        $responsesData = $this->It_response->find('all', array('conditions' => array('It_response.ticket_id' => $id));

        //setting the variables in the ticket view.
        $this->set('ticket', $ticketData);
        $this->set('responses', $responsesData);

    }
```

Anyway, if your ticket is correctly linked to the response model, you would only need to do one query which would contain an array of Responses.

Answer (score 0):

To archive this you need to define all the correct associations inside model.

According to your question i guess your ItRequest model are related to ItResponse with hasMany relationship so directly your Response table has one-to-one relation with Request Table.

so define it and then just query it inside controller and display it inside view file as your need.

[cakephp model association (view)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054493/cakephp-model-association-view/15059884#15059884)

[CakePHP model JOINS, missing fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494861/cakephp-model-joins-missing-fields/14495492#14495492)

[Retrieving Data From two tables that are associated with a forign key in CakePhp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517134/retrieving-data-from-two-tables-that-are-associated-with-a-forign-key-in-cakephp/14517503#14517503)